# groupby by many columns in pandas and add it into one dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that I made from stackoverflow survey 2018 and 2019. I have a column that is the salary for this specific respondent and I call it 'usd' and many columns of programming languages names - c,c++,c#, etc - 43 of them, so total 44 columns - 1 is salary and the others are programming languages.
Each row has the salary of the respondent and the languages they work with, its 1 if he work with the language of this column and 0 if not.
Now, what I want to do is to do a groupby for each of these programming languages and get the mean of salary - the mean of the usd column and then append it or merge or concat so I have the average salary for each programming language.
If you have any other idea as to how to get to this goal I'd be happy to learn it
for now this is what I have :

```
y=pd.DataFrame( )
for x in df2.columns:
    if x!='usd':
        a=df2.groupby(x).mean()
        y=y.append(a)
```

It's not very amazing since if I just do 
`df2.groupby('C').mean()`
or
`df2.groupby('Python').mean()`

then it shows me each time the programming language name I have but with my for loop it doesnt and this is actually what I am looking for a solution for.

right now the df looks like this loos like this:

```
usd        c python c# SQL c++ ruby ...etc..       
50000      1 0       1  1   0   1
100000     0 1       0  1   1   1
.
.
.
etc

and what i want to get is
     usd
c 
1    mean of usd columns for those with 1 under c column
0    mean of usd columns for those with 0 under c column
c++  
1    mean of usd columns for those with 1 under c++ column
0    mean of usd columns for those with 0 under c++ column
.
.
.
.
```

Thanks!

Thanks!!

Comment: So, I assume, you want the mean of the 'usd' of all the rows that have a particular language (ex- python or java) as 1, right? In that case, your final output will  be a df with languages as the index and the mean salary column. If you can post a sample data set and the expected result, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.. you have to group them by the language column value and take the mean of the 'usd' column

Sample dataset:

```
 usd  java  python  c
0   10     1       0  1
1   20     0       1  1
2   30     1       1  0
3   40     0       0  1
4   50     1       1  0
```

Code

```
for lang in df.columns[1:]:
    print(df.groupby(lang)['usd'].mean())
```

Result

```
java
0    30
1    30

python
0    25.000000
1    33.333333

c
0    40.000000
1    23.333333
```

You can concat/merge the results into a df.

Code

```
for lang in df.columns[1:]:
    group_lang = (df.groupby(lang)['usd'].mean().reset_index())
    group_lang['lang'] = lang
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, group_lang[['lang','usd']]])

df2=df2.reset_index().set_index('lang').rename(columns={'index':'val'})
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
        val        usd
lang                  
java      0  30.000000
java      1  30.000000
python    0  25.000000
python    1  33.333333
c         0  40.000000
c         1  23.333333
```

There may be a better solution, but this should work. Let me know how it goes. Cheers :)

Comment: hi, thanks for the help,
I tried the code,
and unfortunatly what it does is only get the last lang and my guess is that it has to do with this line: group_lang['lang'] = lang
because in the last run of the for loop it is being taking the lang of this iteration
but then again this just my guess
so i get only WebAssembly
anyway i dont get excatly the same thing as in your result, which is excatly what i need
your solution however is very iluminating, so thanks!

Comment: @dave is your data similar to what I have taken for sample? can you post a subset of your dataset (just 10 -20 line) or point me to the data set you are using? When you just print this `for lang in df.columns[1:]:
    print(df.groupby(lang)['usd'].mean())` does it give you the right counts?

Comment: yes,if i run only this code then it is great since it gives me the right output
for example:
Assembly
0.00   56,565.06
1.00   52,370.76
Name: usd, dtype: float64
Bash/Shell
0.00   44,801.57
1.00   58,446.32
Name: usd, dtype: float64
C
0.00   57,205.63
1.00   52,435.51
Name: usd, dtype: float64
C#
0.00   55,760.34
1.00   57,515.54
Name: usd, dtype: float64
and so on,its missing the header usd and concatenation,
thanks so much!
i tried to copy it so you see how the output looks at my screen but it doesnt really shows it vertically, but u probably understand how it looks like

Comment: the dataset is a data frame with 44 columns, the first one is usd, and the others are programming languages
and then in the usd column are different numbers that are different salaries and in the columns of the programming languages are 0 or 1 - if either or not the person work with this language, it is in a lot of cases that in a row there are many 1 since a person might work with many languages
i just want to know what is the average salary for each of those lagnuges
cheers:)

Comment: @dave if the dataset is similar then it should work.. basically the code is looping through each language and grouping it using the column value to get the mean. So here you will have 2 columns for the groupby-dataframe - the language and the mean usd. With the `reset_index`it is flattened now. With this statement `group_lang['lang'] = lang` we add the new column 'lang' with the actual value of the column name used to groupby. so now you have 2 rows with 3 columns - lang value, mean usd and column 'lang'.  Now we concat these groupby dataframes to get the final result.

Comment: just to make sure - in this line - df2 = pd.concat([df2, group_lang[['lang','usd']]])
what you actually meant was df2 = pd.concat([df, group_lang[['lang','usd']]])?
i get an error:
NameError: name 'df2' is not defined
?

Comment: ok, i define a new df2=pd.DataFrame()
and now it works!!!!
Thanks so much!!!
Amaizing!!!

Comment: Great. I must have missed it while pasting the code here.

Comment: i did upvote but since i dont have a lot of points or something it does not show publicly